# bash script that reads each line of a file and stores to different variables (but got command not found message)

Tags: bash, loops, sed, command, execute

Thanks for your help in advance.  I'm writing a simple bash script, which just read each line of a file, and then store each line into a different variable.  For example, I'd like the script to perform the following commands:

```
d1=AER
d2=BHR
d3=CEF
...
```

Therefore, I have a text file that has 10 lines, and each line is the content of the variables I'd like to store (e.g., AER), and I have the following test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10..1}
do
    $(d$i=$(sed -n ${i}p $HOME/textfile.txt))
done
```

However,when executing the script, it gave me

```
./test.sh: line 4: d1=AER: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: d2=BHR: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: d3=CEF: command not found
...
```

,instead of storing the characters into corresponding variables.  Could somebody please identify where I did it wrong?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your script is that if you need to interpolate a variable on the first line, bash thinks its the name of a program and tries to execute it. You can eval it, to make the variable:

```
eval "d$i=$(sed ...)"
```

but its much simpler to use the read bash built-in, since it takes line input to a specified variable. Here's one way to do it:

```
for ((i=1;; i++)); do
    read "d$i" || break;
done < textfile.txt
echo "$d1"
echo "$d2"
```

Comment: thanks a lot not only for the solution, but also the clear explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Use an array, but the right way.

```
read -a d -d '\n' < textfile.txt
echo "${d[1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the array solution, you can use `eval`.

```
((lnum=1))
exec 3< ${filetoread}
while read -u3 line
do
  eval `echo d${lnum}=\"${line}\"`
  ((lnum=1+${lnum}))
done
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: Small comment - you can use self increment: `let lnum++` or `((lnum++))``

Comment: Much better to use the `declare` command than `eval`: `declare d${lnum}="$line"

Comment: @chepner nice! (+1), I didn't realize/think-to declare/typeset/local to construct symbol names.

Comment: @twalberg  something else that bugs me here is the FD...   I mean I have used this before, but when you try to write reusable functions its kinda hard to know that you caller does not yet make use of FD#3

Comment: You can just redirect standard input for the loop--`while read line; do ...; done < $filetoread`--as long as the `read` command is the only thing in the loop that reads from standard input.

Comment: Ok, valid points, all, but the point of the answer was the `eval` bit - the rest was just to make it a working example, and not intended to be interpreted as the "best" way to do it... There are quite a few different ways to skin the rest of that cat... And having more experience with `ksh` scripting than `bash`, I didn't think of the `declare` option either...